# Import csv mysql with multiple custom date formats

Tags: mysql, date, csv

I have to import a csv into a mysql database with a funny date format so I decided to use STR_TO_Date() to convert it, however it pulls an error on the second conversion when I try to put multiple conversions for the dates.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/the.csv'
INTO TABLE data
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(ID, UID, Barcode, Name, @Start, @End, Seconds)
SET Start = STR_TO_DATE(@Start, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i')
SET End = STR_TO_DATE(@End, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i')`

My database looks along the lines of:

```
ID  UID     Barcode Name        Start               End                 Seconds
29  12345   BBB6168 namehere    09/12/2014 18:00    09/12/2014 18:09    538
30  12345   AAA6168 namehere    10/12/2014 11:01    10/12/2014 11:02    4
31  AAAAA   ABC6084 namehere    10/12/2014 11:34    10/12/2014 11:34    5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would import the data as a string (`varchar`) and convert it to the desired format after you've imported it

Comment: Can you give an example Barranka? Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barranka mentioned, its probably best to import into a table of string (varchar) columns and then run an insert into your final table.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/the.csv'
INTO TABLE data_temp_strings
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(ID, UID, Barcode, Name, StartStr, EndStr, Seconds);


INSERT INTO data (ID,UID,Barcode,Name,Start,End,Seconds)
SELECT  ID,
        UID,
        Barcode,
        Name,
        STR_TO_DATE(StartStr, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i'),
        STR_TO_DATE(EndStr, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i'),
        Seconds
FROM   data_temp_strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [MySQL documentation for LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) the code would be the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/the.csv'
INTO TABLE data
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(ID, UID, Barcode, Name, @Start, @End, Seconds)
SET Start = STR_TO_DATE(@Start, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i'),
    End = STR_TO_DATE(@End, '%d/%c/%Y %H:%i');
```

Bonus: [MySQL STR_TO_DATE() format options](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp).